# Calculate total time of each contributor's segments and sum of all duration attribute values of the elements pc:chapter

Tags: xml, sum, key, xslt-1.0

I hope the question is clear. I want the sum of the "speech share" from guest and host seperatly and for each episode.

Here is an example of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pc:podcast url="https://forschergeist.de/" version="0.3" xmlns:pc="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3" xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="   https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3   podcast.xsd   https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1   podcast-transcript.xsd">
    <pc:title>Forschergeist</pc:title>
    <pc:persons>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="timpritlove">Tim Pritlove</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="michaelsonnabend">Michael Sonnabend</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="annettevogt">Annette Vogt</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="peterfinke">Peter Finke</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="barbaralenz">Barbara Lenz</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="suatyilmaz">Suat Yilmaz</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="onurgüntürkün">Onur Güntürkün</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="martinlindner">Martin Lindner</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="petereisenberg">Peter Eisenberg</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="michaelschermann">Michael Schermann</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="henrikmüller">Henrik Müller</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="antjeboetius">Antje Boetius</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="gunterdueck">Gunter Dueck</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="ferdischüth">Ferdi Schüth</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="claudiaeggert">Claudia Eggert</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="dagmarschäfer">Dagmar Schäfer</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="murielhelbig">Muriel Helbig</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="nikolauskriegeskorte">Nikolaus Kriegeskorte</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="ulinkarublak">Ulinka Rublack</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="michaelbraungart">Michael Braungart</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="pascalhetze">Pascal Hetze</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="lindabreitlauch">Linda Breitlauch</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="jürgenhandke">Jürgen Handke</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="franzjosefradermacher">Franz Josef Radermacher</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="klauskümmerer">Klaus Kümmerer</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="uweschneidewind">Uwe Schneidewind</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="eberhardknobloch">Eberhard Knobloch</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="ulrichdirnagl">Ulrich Dirnagl</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="hansjoosten">Hans Joosten</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="angelikabrandt">Angelika Brandt</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="andreaszick">Andreas Zick</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="güntherziegler">Günther Ziegler</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="michaelvogel">Michael Vogel</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="siljagraupe">Silja Graupe</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="ernstpeterfischer">Ernst Peter Fischer</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="juliaoffe">Julia Offe</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="pavelrichter">Pavel Richter</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="benjaminlahusen">Benjamin Lahusen</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="reinholdleinfelder">Reinhold Leinfelder</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="claudiahornberg">Claudia Hornberg</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="monikatrümper">Monika Trümper</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="jörnloviscach">Jörn Loviscach</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="lisarosa">Lisa Rosa</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="ralfstockmann">Ralf Stockmann</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="lyndalroper">Lyndal Roper</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="jürgentautz">Jürgen Tautz</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="stefankröpelin">Stefan Kröpelin</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="christophcorves">Christoph Corves</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="jöranmuußmerholz">Jöran Muußmerholz</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="hannshatt">Hanns Hatt</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="carolinbock">Carolin Bock</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="andreaniehaus">Andrea Niehaus</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="volkerquaschning">Volker Quaschning</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="jochenrabe">Jochen Rabe</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="haraldlesch">Harald Lesch</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="sebastiankuhn">Sebastian Kuhn</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="manfredniekisch">Manfred Niekisch</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="christopherzimmermann">Christopher Zimmermann</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="philippewampfler">Philippe Wampfler</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="stefanrahmstorf">Stefan Rahmstorf</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="julespecht">Jule Specht</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="isabelrink">Isabel Rink</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="ingosass">Ingo Sass</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="robertranisch">Robert Ranisch</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="anitagohdes">Anita Gohdes</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="gerdgigerenzer">Gerd Gigerenzer</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="female" pid="alinakokoschka">Alina Kokoschka</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="oliverparodi">Oliver Parodi</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="justushaukap">Justus Haukap</pc:person>
        <pc:person gender="male" pid="peterpurgathofer">Peter Purgathofer</pc:person>
    </pc:persons>
<pc:episode date="2019-10-01T11:00:00" duration="01:53:23" episode="72" title="Verantwortung in der Informatik" url="https://forschergeist.de/podcast/fg072-verantwortung-in-der-informatik/">
        <pc:contributor pid="timpritlove" role="host"/>
        <pc:contributor pid="peterpurgathofer" role="guest"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="00:42" number="1" title="Intro"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="00:46" number="2" title="Begrüßung"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="08:26" number="3" title="Peter Purgathofer"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="09:26" number="4" title="Ethik und Moral in der Informatik"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="06:41" number="5" title="Entscheidung und Verantwortung"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="11:22" number="6" title="Denkweisen in der Informatik"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="00:55" number="7" title="Strukturierung des Kurses"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="05:31" number="8" title="Pre-Scientific Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="04:15" number="9" title="Scientific Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="06:01" number="10" title="Mathematical Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="07:35" number="11" title="Computational Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="09:57" number="12" title="Design Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="10:20" number="13" title="Critical Thinking und Diversity"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="05:15" number="14" title="Responsible Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="04:00" number="15" title="Creative Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="02:18" number="16" title="Economical Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="04:07" number="17" title="Criminal Thinking"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="02:07" number="18" title="Denkweisen für die Wissenschaft"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="11:45" number="19" title="Der Reifegrad der Informatik"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="01:43" number="20" title="Ausklang"/>
        <pt:transcript version="0.1" xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1">
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:00:49.300" start="00:00:43.101">Hallo und herzlich willkommen zu Forschergeist, dem Podcast des Stifterverbands für die deutsche Wissenschaft.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:00:57.600" start="00:00:49.301">Mein Name ist Tim Pritlove und ich begrüße alle zu Ausgabe Nummer 72 hier in unserer Gesprächsreihe rund um Wissenschaft,</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:04.300" start="00:00:57.601">wissenschaftliche Fragen, manchmal geht es um Wissenschaft, manchmal geht es auch um die Metafragen der Wissenschaft.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:08.100" start="00:01:04.301">Und ein solches Thema erwartet uns heute.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:17.000" start="00:01:08.101">Dafür bin ich mal wieder ein wenig gereist, konkret bin ich nach Wien gefahren an die TU Wien.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:26.400" start="00:01:17.001">Dort sitze ich jetzt im Institut für Visual Computing and Human-Centered Technology und begrüße meinen Gesprächspartner, nämlich den Peter, Peter Purgathofer.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:27.300" start="00:01:26.401">Schönen guten Tag.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="peterpurgathofer" end="00:01:29.200" start="00:01:27.301">Hallo.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:34.100" start="00:01:29.201">Peter, wir kennen uns schon eine Weile, du bist schon ganz schön lange hier oder?</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="peterpurgathofer" end="00:01:39.500" start="00:01:34.101">Ja, ich habe vor, glaube ich, zwei Jahren meine 25-jährige Jubiläumszahlung bekommen.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:41.100" start="00:01:39.501">Guck an.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="peterpurgathofer" end="00:01:45.000" start="00:01:41.101">Auch so eine Art Bookmark, die man im Leben seiner Tätigkeit hat.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:50.500" start="00:01:45.001">Ja. Und konkret bist du aber schon immer der Informatik zugehörig gewesen.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="peterpurgathofer" end="00:01:50.600" start="00:01:50.501">Immer.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:52.400" start="00:01:50.601">Immer.</pt:segment>
<pc:episode date="2019-09-05T14:48:00" duration="02:29:05" episode="71" title="Wirtschaft und Wettbewerb" url="https://forschergeist.de/podcast/fg071-wirtschaft-und-wettbewerb/">
        <pc:contributor pid="timpritlove" role="host"/>
        <pc:contributor pid="justushaucap" role="guest"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="00:42" number="1" title="Intro"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="01:04" number="2" title="Begrüßung"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="12:28" number="3" title="Persönlicher Hintergrund"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="02:36" number="4" title="Instutute of Competition Economics (DICE)"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="04:57" number="5" title="Monopolkommission"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="11:10" number="6" title="Unser Wirtschaftssystem"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="12:02" number="7" title="Marktversagen"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="07:33" number="8" title="Liberalisierungen und natürliche Monopole"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="08:41" number="9" title="Öffentliche Straßen"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="05:22" number="10" title="Lenkungsfunktionen"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="12:41" number="11" title="Telekommunikationsmarkt"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="04:58" number="12" title="Trägheit der Entwicklung"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="07:14" number="13" title="Soziale Umverteilung"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="10:22" number="14" title="Erneuerbare-Energien-Gesetz"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="12:59" number="15" title="Drogenlegalisierung"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="11:39" number="16" title="Medienmarkt und öffentlicher Rundfunk"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="15:26" number="17" title="Digitalwirtschaft und neue Monopole"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="02:30" number="18" title="Zukünftige Baustellen"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="03:21" number="19" title="Fortschritte in der Wirtschaftsforschung"/>
        <pc:chapter duration="01:12" number="20" title="Ausklang"/>
        <pt:transcript version="0.1" xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1">
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:00:49.000" start="00:00:43.401">Hallo und herzlich willkommen zu Forschergeist, dem Podcast des Stifterverbands für die deutsche Wissenschaft.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:00.700" start="00:00:49.001">Mein Name ist Tim Pritlove und ich begrüße alle zu Ausgabe Nummer 71 unserer immer weiter voranschreitenden Gesprächsserie über alle möglichen Einblicke,</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:07.400" start="00:01:00.701">die uns die Wissenschaft bietet oder die wir vielleicht auch selbst in die Wissenschaft hier gewinnen wollen.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:15.400" start="00:01:07.401">Und nun haben wir ja schon einen ziemlich breites Bouquet an Themen abgearbeitet hier in den letzten fünf Jahren.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:19.100" start="00:01:15.401">Eins ist ein bisschen zu kurz gekommen, die Wirtschaft.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:29.200" start="00:01:19.101">Was nicht bedeutet, dass das uninteressant ist und vor allem ist ja auch die Erkenntnis, dass Wirtschaft nicht nur stattfindet und ein tägliches politisches Thema ist,</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:33.900" start="00:01:29.201">sondern dass daran auch geforscht wird, auch nochmal ganz interessant.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:41.500" start="00:01:33.901">Und um darüber ein wenig zu sprechen, insbesondere über die Fragen des Wettbewerbs in der Wirtschaft, begrüßte ich zunächst einmal meinen Gesprächspartner,</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:43.500" start="00:01:41.501">nämlich Justus Haukap, schönen guten Tag.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="justushaucap" end="00:01:43.700" start="00:01:43.501">Ja, guten Tag.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:47.200" start="00:01:43.701">Herzlich willkommen bei Forschergeist.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:01:57.700" start="00:01:47.201">Ja, Herr Haukap, sie sind in Düsseldorf, dort als Wirtschaftswissenschaftler an der Heinrich-Heine-Universität aktiv.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:05.300" start="00:01:57.701">Dort auch mittlerweile Dekan der wirtschaftswissenschaftlichen Fakultät, wenn ich das richtig sehe.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="justushaucap" end="00:02:05.900" start="00:02:05.301">Gewesen.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:07.700" start="00:02:05.901">Gewesen, ist schon wieder vorbei?</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="justushaucap" end="00:02:08.000" start="00:02:07.701">Genau.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:12.500" start="00:02:08.001">Ach okay, gut na dann wissen wir es jetzt.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:15.700" start="00:02:12.501">Aber das wird ja sicherlich auch einen gewissen Vorlauf gehabt haben.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:19.200" start="00:02:15.701">Wie interessiert man sich denn eigentlich für Wirtschaft?</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:22.800" start="00:02:19.201">Weil ich fand das ja eigentlich ein bisschen unspannend.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:25.900" start="00:02:22.801">Ich weiß nicht genau warum, aber war so.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:29.400" start="00:02:25.901">Und ich dachte mir immer so, ich mache lieber Computer.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" end="00:02:37.500" start="00:02:29.401">Gibt es da irgendwie so einen Auslöser oder war das so, entweder was mit Tieren oder was mit Wirtschaft?</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="justushaucap" end="00:02:38.400" start="00:02:37.501">Irgendwas mit Medien.</pt:segment>
</pc:podcast>
```

My XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pc="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3"
xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast- 
transcript/0.1" 
exclude-result-prefixes="pc pt">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="person" match="pc:person" use="@pid"/>
<xsl:key name="segment" match="pt:segment" use="@contributor"/>

<xsl:template match="/pc:podcast">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Your title</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pc:episode/pc:contributor" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pc:contributor">
    <p>
        <xsl:text>Episode </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@episode"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('person', @pid)"/>
        <xsl:text> Total time: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="sum-durations">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('segment', @pid)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text> seconds</xsl:text>
    </p>
    <p>
        <xsl:text>Total time</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="milliseconds-to-time">
                  <xsl:with-param name="milliseconds" select="nodes"/>
        </xsl:call-template>    


    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum-durations">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($nodes)">
            <xsl:variable name="node" select="$nodes[1]" />
            <xsl:variable name="start">
                <xsl:call-template name="time2sec">
                    <xsl:with-param name="time" select="$node/@start"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="end">
                <xsl:call-template name="time2sec">
                    <xsl:with-param name="time" select="$node/@end"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum-durations">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $end - $start"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="time2sec">
    <xsl:param name="time"/>
    <xsl:param name="h" select="substring-before($time, ':')"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="substring-before(substring-after($time,':'),':')"/>
    <xsl:param name="s" select="substring-after(substring-after($time,':'),':')"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="3600*$h + 60*$m + $s"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="milliseconds-to-time">
    <xsl:param name="milliseconds"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor($milliseconds div 3600000)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="floor($milliseconds div 60000) mod 60"/>
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="$milliseconds mod 60000 div 1000"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '00')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, ':00')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($s, ':00.###')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output should be something like this:

```
Epsiode 72: Peter Burghofer: ... Minutes or: 00:45:22.233
Episode 72: Tim Pritlove ... Minutes or: 00:23:12.675 
Episode lenght of Episode 72: 01:53:23
```

What's the best way to handle/solve this problem? Any advice/suggestions? Can you provide me an example of how it should look like?

Comment: When you post a not well-formed XML input, we have nothing to test our answer with. So we need to either waste our time correcting your input or post an untested answer.

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I have answered it. If you have additional questions, please post them separately (and make sure we can understand them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the sum of the "speech share"

There is no "speech share" in the XML you show. I am assuming you meant the total time of each contributor's segments. This is not trivial to do in XSLT 1.0.

First, you need to compute the individual `pt:segment` durations. For this, you need to convert the `start` and `end` times to seconds (or some other common unit) so that you can subtract them. And you need to convert the results to a `node-set` so that they can be summed.

Try something like the following:

**XSLT 1.0 (+ EXSLT)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pc="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3"
xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="pc pt"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="person" match="pc:person" use="@pid"/>
<xsl:key name="segment" match="pt:segment" use="@contributor"/>

<xsl:template match="/pc:podcast">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Your title</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pc:episode/pc:contributor" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pc:contributor">
    <p>
        <xsl:text>Episode </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@episode"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('person', @pid)"/>
        <xsl:text> Total time: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="durations">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('segment', @pid)">
                <xsl:variable name="start">
                    <xsl:call-template name="time2sec">
                        <xsl:with-param name="time" select="@start"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="end">
                    <xsl:call-template name="time2sec">
                        <xsl:with-param name="time" select="@end"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <duration>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$end - $start"/>
                </duration>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($durations)/duration)"/>
        <xsl:text> seconds</xsl:text>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="time2sec">
    <xsl:param name="time"/>
    <xsl:param name="h" select="substring-before($time, ':')"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="substring-before(substring-after($time,':'),':')"/>
    <xsl:param name="s" select="substring-after(substring-after($time,':'),':')"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="3600*$h + 60*$m + $s"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To do the same thing in pure XSLT 1.0, with no extension functions, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pc="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3"
xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1" 
exclude-result-prefixes="pc pt">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="person" match="pc:person" use="@pid"/>
<xsl:key name="segment" match="pt:segment" use="@contributor"/>

<xsl:template match="/pc:podcast">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Your title</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pc:episode/pc:contributor" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pc:contributor">
    <p>
        <xsl:text>Episode </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@episode"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('person', @pid)"/>
        <xsl:text> Total time: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="sum-durations">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('segment', @pid)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text> seconds</xsl:text>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum-durations">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($nodes)">
            <xsl:variable name="node" select="$nodes[1]" />
            <xsl:variable name="start">
                <xsl:call-template name="time2sec">
                    <xsl:with-param name="time" select="$node/@start"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="end">
                <xsl:call-template name="time2sec">
                    <xsl:with-param name="time" select="$node/@end"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum-durations">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $end - $start"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="time2sec">
    <xsl:param name="time"/>
    <xsl:param name="h" select="substring-before($time, ':')"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="substring-before(substring-after($time,':'),':')"/>
    <xsl:param name="s" select="substring-after(substring-after($time,':'),':')"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="3600*$h + 60*$m + $s"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but I'am getting an error: "Unregistered function".

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using the software "XML Copy Editor". I think it's using Saxon.

Comment: Please find out - see here how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153 Is that the exact error message or is there more?

Comment: Processor is: libxslt and Version is: 1.0 The exact error message is: "Transformation not possible: Error at line 0: Unregistered function"

Comment: This is very strange. The libxslt processor certainly supports the EXSLT `node-set()` extension function I have used. And there is no function on line 0. I have added a "pure" XSLT 1.0 solution to my answer. If that doesn't work for you, then I don't know what will.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work so far. Now can can you still show me how to calculate the sum of the durations values of the elements pc:chapter for all pc:episodes? So for example 00:41+00:10= 00:51...

Comment: The same way: convert them to seconds (or milliseconds), sum the results and convert the sum back to time.

Comment: Short update: I have tested your solution but now I'm getting the following output:                       
Your title

Episode 72: Tim Pritlove Total time: NaN seconds

Episode 72: Peter Purgathofer Total time: NaN seconds

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with a problem I cannot reproduce. I have tested my answer using a corrected input. You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3bY

Comment: Thanks anyway. I think the problem is related to the software.